# Wildcard character search in Google, but for individual letters?

Tags: google-search

For instance, I would like to search on a website "3XX lessons". I know that Google allows "XXX lessons" with "* lessons", but how do you use the wildcard symbol for individual characters in a string?

Comment: You can't do individual character wildcards in a Google search, but you can do a number range. Maybe `300..399 lessons` will suit your needs.

Comment: Oh that's a clever workaround! That does help :) If you wrote an answer I'd have marked it as the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

try to use ~ 
i have tried it and worked for me

Comment: Could you give an example in your answer, please?

Comment: The tilde gives synonyms and word variants. While it may still work, it appears that Google no longer maintains it. See Rubén's answer at:
https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/99496/wildcards-in-google-advanced-search