# Wildcards in Google advanced search

Tags: google-search, search-operators

I have been using Google advanced search operators like `intext:`, `inurl`, `intitle`, etc. And I know that when search in Google we can use `*` as a wildcard operator.

But I have tried to used `*` as the wildcard operator in advance search operators. As a example `intext:scien*` to search words like science, scientific, etc. And it seems to be not working.

Can anyone please tell me how to use wildcards in Google advanced search operators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short answer

At this time Google doesn't have an operator for word variants.

## Explanation

Google used to have tilde `~` as search operator for word variants but it was retired<sup>1</sup> from the official help article<sup>2</sup>.

## References

<sup>1</sup>: [Google's Tilde Operator No Longer Works](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2013/06/googles-tilde-operator-no-longer-works.html)
<sup>2</sup>: [Search operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en)